# Strong thin rope for kite

Tags: material-selection

**Background**: I never built a functioning kite (I had a few attempts, as a child), I never successfully raised a kite (no stable wind with enough force when a ready-made kite was available).

**Current situation**: I had an idea to finally build a working kite, BUT also to be able to raise it as high as possible - maybe several kilometers?

**Question**: what kind of **rope** is **thin** enough and also **strong** enough to make my plan successful?

I guess that for low heights, strength is not an issue, but for my plan, the situation is different. On the internet I found information more about the kite itself, and about how to tie the knots, rather than the better materials to be used.

Of course, I have in mind also the volume and the weight of the said rope, since I will have to transport it somehow.

Other related questions [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8564/rolling-the-rope-of-a-kite) and [here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8565/how-to-make-kite-line-more-visible).

Comment: I would look at fishing line.  It is light in weight, available in different strengths and in huge spools, particularly for big game fishing, which requires serious line lengths.  The hardware for game fishing might also address your related question on managing the line.  Posting this as a comment because I'm not a kite flyer or fisherman, and have no hands-on experience.

Comment: I'd like to issue a warning that if your kite will be a big and flying as high as it sounds, you absolutely need to anchor it to the ground. There are some commercial display kites that are required to be anchored to a car of a minimum weight (like an SUV). Please keep your own safety in mind.

Comment: @fixer1234: for a first draft, I will try fishing line. Most likely, ordinary fishing line, not the one suitable for whale fishing (ignoring that whales are not fish). Maybe even the fishing reeling "system".

Comment: I would start with buying a kite, ready made or a set to make a kite, and get used to what kites are and how they behave. Then when you have some experience you go to a site where kite people hang out and start with reading and asking questions, best a site where people in your country come. And remember that high flying kites may be a problem for air traffic and may be forbidden.

Comment: You do realise that the world record for altitude gained by a single kite is under 5km? And it was set on a wide-open, nicely flat 50km^2 ranch where there was no chance of losing control and hitting someone with a kite moving at 100km/h? This seems a bit of a big ask for a self-confessed novice.

Comment: @Gwyn: yes, I understand all those. I already mentioned the safety concerns, as well as the risk of interference with other flying objects (that is why I asked a dedicated question for that). What is your point?

Comment: You are asking many questions that border on far fetched, each one going in deeper and deeper. You have been given good answers, and good advice, that you refuse to accept because it does not meet your impossible expectations.

Comment: @rebusB Most places a line of more than 50m is actually illegal, certainly anywhere where you're likely to encounter "intelligent fliers" as mentioned in one of the related questions....

Comment: To try and put this in perspective: Unless you have access to a piece of level, privately owned land in excess  of 30 square kilometers in area with no  chance of random hikers or livestock on the ground or air traffic over it, you're likely to spend the night in jail if you try this with a line anywhere near a kilometre long.  Even if you do have the perfect spot, you'll still need to obtain special clearance from national or state air traffic control and have to stick to a narrow pre-approved time slot.

Comment: @Gwyn: You are deviating from the question big time. I am aware (as explained already) of the safety and law issues. My "unknown" of the first interest (the actual question) is technical. If you cannot contribute, it is no problem, I will not have hard feelings.

Comment: Well, since you don't answer questions about the kite design, size, mass, or give a drawing, it's a bit difficult to actually help you in any other way. Like any engineer, (or kite enthusiast) the "client" no matter how little versed s/he may be in the math, physics, etc needs to at least be able to give us some indication of what they want to achieve or design is impossible. At minimum, we need to know the dimensions and materials of construction of your kite, and how many lines on your rig, in order to do the calculations and suggest the right type of line, winch design, motor size etc.

Comment: @Gwyn: Thanks for the careful explanation. Nobody asked that specific question, and I did not think of it as important. As of now, I am at the stage to "(technically) dream" about the entire project. I did not make any choice of materials, sizes etc. It will depend not only on what I want, but also on what will be available to purchase. I have in mind the rhomboid shape, (about) 1m x 2 m (maybe smaller at the beginning, maybe bigger later). But anything might change, once I start building and experimenting. I am willing to adapt while progressing.

Comment: If you put that description into your questions, you'll probably get answers that are a lot more useful.  That would probably not steer easily on longer lines, so I'd still advise you to fly it on a shorter line (20-30m) for the first few outings to get a feel for it, probably on a two line rig with what we call a hammock style attachment (not sure what it's called elsewhere in the world) I'll see if I can dredge up some designs or at least sketches for you ...

Answer (score 6):

Kite string is a product. It is designed to be strong and light to enable kites to fly under optimum conditions. For ordinary kites, ordinary kite string is sufficient.

High performance kites (large lift capability, stunt/performing kites) require higher breaking strength while retaining light weight.

Spectra line is constructed of high density polyethylene and is quite light and strong. I have used 1 mm thick x 2 mm wide Spectra line which had a breaking strength of 700 pounds. Another feature of this type of line is that it has very low stretch.

In the case of multi-line stunt kites, it's critical to have the lines remain at a specific length in flight. Spectra does this well.

Spectra is a brand name and the product can be found under other names.

Comment: Before I asked the questions, and before I read your answers, I did not even know how / what to search on the net regarding the subject of kites. I made a short search on Amazon, and I did not find the monster string you described. What length does is it have? I am curious. I will keep searching. I am not in the US, btw.